Rigour, Intuition for Lebesgue Integrability
I'm a second year undergraduate maths student. I have some difficulty determining the Lebesgue integrability of some functions. I think my main issue is that I don't know how to rigorously determine these things, relying too heavily on my (quite minimal) intuition of decay rates of functions and whatnot without the actual mathematics to back it up.
Here are functions that I have issue with:

$g(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x^{5/4
}}$ for $x \neq 0$. Show that $g$ is integrable on $(0,\infty)$.

Let $u(x,t) = \frac{e^{tx}-1}{x\sqrt{1-x}}$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $x \mapsto u(x,t)$ is Lebesgue integrable on $(0,1)$ for every $t$.

Suppose $f$ is continuous and Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(x,y)=e^{-x^2}f(e^{-x^2/2}y)$. Show that $g$ is Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}^2$.


Here are my attempts to each question:

$g$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$, so $g$ is measurable on $(0,\infty)$, and on $(1,\infty)$, $0 \leq |g(x)| \leq \frac{1}{x^{5/4}}$, which is integrable since $\frac{1}{x^\alpha}$ is integrable for $\alpha >1$ (I know this), so $g$ is integrable over $(0,1)$. For $(0,1)$, we have a singularity at $x=0$. The main issue from here is that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{5/4}}$ tends to infinity as $x \to 0$ at a rate of about $\frac{1}{x^{1/4}}$. From here, I can't see where to finish off the proof.

$x \mapsto u(x,t)$ is Lebesgue integrable on $(0,1)$ for every $t$ if for every $t$, $\int_{0}^1 u(x,t) dx < \infty $. From here, I see the singularities are at 0,1, but that's about it. Expanding $e^{tx}$ or $(1-x)^{-1/2}$ do not seem helpful in this case, complicating things too much. What can I do from here?

We should use Fubini's Theorem and Tonelli's Theorem. Particularly, since $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, we know that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(e^{-x^2/2}y) dy <\infty$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R^2}$. The issue for me is that there might be some function $f(x)$ such that the integral of $f(x)$, dependent on $x$, might grow at a rate of $e^{x^2}$, which then makes $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(e^{-x^2/2}y) dy ) dx$ not
integrable.


Is there a general approach or set of ideas to approach these questions with?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! If someone can also provide me with the "intuitive" reasoning behind the rigour, I'd be so thankful!

I'll start by saying Lebesgue integrability does not have much to do with decay of functions, per se. It has more to do with the measure of level sets (see the theorem at the bottom of the answer). Now about your three problems.
For points (1) and (2), you need to think about integrability of the function $x^{-p}$ on $(0,1)$. For which $p$ is $\int_0^1 x^{-p}\,dx<\infty$? Recall that $\sin x\sim x$ as $x\to0$.
This is apparent in (1). In (2), you may have to squint your eyes, but if you consider that $\sqrt{x(1-x)} = \sqrt x\cdot \sqrt{1-x}$, then you may see you need to consider the behavior of the integrand separately for $x$ close to $0$ and $x$ close to $1$. The hint is that $\int_0^1 x^{-1/2}\,dx$ converges.
For (3), use Fubini--Tonelli:
$$
\iint e^{-x^2}f(e^{-x^2/2}y)\,dx\,dy = \int e^{-x^2}\int f(e^{-x^2/2}y)\,dy\,dx.
$$
For every fixed $x$, the inner integral can be done by changing variable, letting $z = e^{-x^2/2}y$. When you change variable, you get
$$
\int e^{-x^2}e^{x^2/2}\int f(z)\,dz\,dx.
$$
Can you see how to finish (3) now?

The general approach to addressing Lebesgue integrability is to consider level sets.
Theorem. A function $f$ on a domain $D$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}2^n\cdot \mathrm{meas}[\{x\in D:2^n<|f(x)|<2^{n+1}\}] < \infty
$$
This theorem and minor variations on it are useful for estimating integrals. A reference is say Stein and Shakarchi's book on measure theory, or any textbook on measure theory. You can practice using the theorem on each (1),(2),(3).
